# iPhone: Asynchronous HEAD method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I am very new here. I am trying to update the content of a file from a webserver only if it has changed. I found an example of code here using a synchronous connection in NSURLconnection.
Is it possible to do asynchronously?

Comment: yes it is possible to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` has the method `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` for synchronous connection. It also has a method `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` for async connection. You need to create a block for `completionHandler` parameter, which handles the response from web server.

Also:

- `initWithRequest:delegate:`
- `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:`
- `start`

are available for async use. You gonna need to implement some methods of `NSURLConnectionDelegate` to handle the async response.

Please refer to [NSURLConnection Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSURLConnectionDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate).

Answer (score -2):

i think [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) is the easiest solution:

set the `request` Method for your `ASIHTTPRequest`

```
// HTTP method to use (eg: GET / POST / PUT / DELETE / HEAD etc). Defaults to GET
NSString *requestMethod;
```

or you can use a [download cache](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#using_a_download_cache)

> ASIHTTPRequest can automatically store downloaded data in a cache for use later. This can be helpful in many situations...